# Pythonic way of slicing a list w.r.t. first element in tuple

Tags: python, tuples, slice, binary-search

I have a sorted list of tuples of the form

```
x = 
[(0,1), (0,2), (0,3), ... 
 (1,1), (1,3), (1,4), ...
 ...
 (n,0), (n,4), ...
]
```

I want to slice the list such that all numbers of (x,y) where x is a certain value in the new list and the order is kept. Now, this would obviously work:

```
y = [(a,b) for (a,b) in x if a == n]
```

But it is really slow. It would be faster to find the first and last index that satisfies this condition with binary search. `index` gives you the first index for a value, and `index` of the reversed list would give the last index. How would apply it though without doing `[a for (a,b) in x]` and copying the whole list, in a pythonic way?

Comment: As it cannot assume an _ordered_ list, `index` probably doesn't do a binary search, but a list traversal, so I doubt that'd be much faster.

Comment: Consider using [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists), the preferred way to handle sorted lists.

Comment: As for accessing the subrange (slice) within your list once you know begin and end position: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation or even just https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by @Liongold, you can use bisect. Assuming you want all tuples `t` with `t[0] == 1`:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

x = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]

start = bisect_left(x, (1, None))  # index of the very first (1, i) 
end = bisect_left(x, (2, None))  # index after the very last (1, i)

y = x[start:end]

# y: [(1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

You can find details in the [bisect docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left).

Comment: What if I can't assume that 2 is in the list?

Comment: `bisect_left(x, (2, None)` will return the insertion point of the provided element. Since `None < i` for any integer `i`, this should always return the exact index after the last `(1, i)`. This can be `len(x)` if necessary